# TextView pushes away other View out of screen inside LinearLayout

Tags: android, textview, android-linearlayout

I am facing an issue with `LinearLayout` where `TextView` is pushing away a view out of the screen. I want the text to go on the next line when less than 100dp space is left after it. I can't use `layout_weight` because I am using a background behind the `TextView` and if I fix the weight then the background will span that much of space even if the text is too small.
This is my code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="4dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtReceiverMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:text="longmessage longmessage longmessage longmessage longmessage longmessage longmessage longmessage longmessage "
        android:background="@drawable/receiver_chat_gradient_background"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>
    <View
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**What I want**

[image]

**What I'm getting:**

[image]

Comment: Introduce some weight. Search for weight in linear layout. You will get your answer.

Comment: @bluetoothfx but if I'll add weight background will be applied to the whole area spaning that weight.

Comment: Think of a linear layout with a horizontal Orientation with wrap content. One control is your text box and another control is view. 1st control weight is 6 and last content weight is 4. I hope it will help you once you understand the weight concept. Hope I understand your problem correctly.

Comment: make width of textview to "0dp" and add `android:layout_weight="1"` for textview

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add the [`layout_weight`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear#Weight) in the `TextView` with a value of 1

Modified layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtReceiverMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/receiver_chat_gradient_background"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="longmessage longmessage longmessage longmessage longmessage longmessage longmessage longmessage longmessage "
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you absolutely have to use a `LinearLayout` here?

I would recommend you use a `ConstraintLayout` instead, that way you have more control over how the Views are drawn at the end.

E.g.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtReceiverMessage"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:text="longmessage longmessage longmessage longmessage longmessage longmessage longmessage longmessage longmessage "
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/view"/>
    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This solution showcases what you're trying to achieve with the same hierarchy that you presented.

Nonetheless, an even better solution would to take advantage of `ConstraintLayout`'s Guidelines in order to keep you `TextView` in place instead of using an empty and otherwise useless `View` to achieve that goal

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtReceiverMessage"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:text="longmessage longmessage longmessage longmessage longmessage longmessage longmessage longmessage longmessage "
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/guideline"/>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_end="100dp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by just adding `android:maxWidth` attribute to the `TextView`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="4dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtReceiverMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:text="message message message message message"
        android:background="@drawable/receiver_chat_gradient_background"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:maxWidth="250dp"/>  //I added this line
</LinearLayout>
```